# How to make ssh based vpn?

Tags: ssh, vpn, tunneling

I have some problems with making ssh-based VPN.

Situation:

```
LOCAL ->            GATE                 -> SERVICES 
                (ssh server)     (Many other servers with some services)
192.168.0.10     10.1.0.154             172.26.106.0/24
255.255.255.0    255.255.0.0
```

From LOCAL I can login through the ssh to the GATE and then from here I have access to all of the SERVICES servers.

However i want to access services directly from my LOCAL computer. How can I acheive this?

Here is what i tried to do after reading ssh manual:

On LOCAL:

```
# ssh -f -w 1:2 root@GATE true
# ifconfig tun1 10.66.1.1 10.66.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.252
# route add -net 172.26.106.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.66.1.2
```

On GATE:

```
# ifconfig tun2 10.66.1.2 10.66.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.252
```

It doesn't work. I get timeouts when i try to ssh to some SERVICE from LOCAL ;-(

Comment: Have you tried this script: https://github.com/oicu/vpn-over-ssh/blob/master/svpn.sh it uses a few more options than you did, which might work better.

Comment: thaaanks! Script itself did not worked for me. But I figured that I needed also to set some rules in iptables to make it work. I adjusted it to my needs, and finally it worked ;-). My script is in the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two and half year left since I asked that question... Now I found another solution which is extremely simple. You can just use tool called `sshuttle`.

From `sshuttle` manual:

> sshuttle allows you to create a VPN connection from your machine to any remote server that you can connect to via ssh, as long as that server has python 2.3 or higher.

i.e.:

```
sshuttle -r user@gate 172.26.100.0/24 172.26.106.0/24 172.26.103.0/24
```

Then in another terminal you can do ssh to any server from routed subnets directly:

i.e.:

```
ssh xyz@172.26.100.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jeff Meden comment I managed to do it. I adjusted that script:
[github.com/oicu/vpn-over-ssh/blob/master/svpn.sh](http://github.com/oicu/vpn-over-ssh/blob/master/svpn.sh) to my needs, and finally it worked:

My version:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH

[ "$(whoami)" != 'root' ] && echo "Run it as root." && exit 1

SERVER_SSH_PORT="22"
SERVER_SSH_IP="10.1.0.154"
CLIENT_TUNNEL="tun5"
SERVER_TUNNEL="tun4"
CLIENT_TUN_IP="192.168.55.5"
SERVER_TUN_IP="192.168.55.4"
TUN_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
CLIENT_ETHERNET="enp12s0"
SERVER_ETHERNET="eth0"
ROUTES=("172.26.100.0/24" "172.26.106.0/24" "172.26.103.0/24")


function start() {
    ssh -NTCf -w "${CLIENT_TUNNEL#tun}:${SERVER_TUNNEL#tun}"  root@${SERVER_SSH_IP} -p ${SERVER_SSH_PORT}
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; 
        then exit 1; 
    fi
    echo "ssh tunnel is working."
    ssh -T root@${SERVER_SSH_IP} -p ${SERVER_SSH_PORT}  << eeooff
        ifconfig ${SERVER_TUNNEL} ${SERVER_TUN_IP} pointopoint ${CLIENT_TUN_IP} netmask ${TUN_NETMASK}
        iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ${CLIENT_TUN_IP}/32 -o ${SERVER_ETHERNET} -j MASQUERADE
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -s ${CLIENT_TUN_IP}/32 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1356
        exit
eeooff

    for ROUTE in ${ROUTES[*]}
    do
        ssh -T root@${SERVER_SSH_IP} -p ${SERVER_SSH_PORT} "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $ROUTE -o ${CLIENT_TUNNEL} -j MASQUERADE"
    done


    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; 
        then exit 1; 
    fi
    echo "remote start."
    ifconfig ${CLIENT_TUNNEL} > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        ifconfig ${CLIENT_TUNNEL} ${CLIENT_TUN_IP} pointopoint ${SERVER_TUN_IP} netmask ${TUN_NETMASK}

        for ROUTE in ${ROUTES[*]}
        do
            ip route add $ROUTE via ${CLIENT_TUN_IP} metric 102
            printf "Adding route: %s\n" $ROUTE
        done

        iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ${SERVER_TUN_IP}/32 -o ${CLIENT_ETHERNET} -j MASQUERADE
        iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -s ${SERVER_TUN_IP}/32 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1356
        for ROUTE in ${ROUTES[*]}
        do
            iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $ROUTE -o ${CLIENT_TUNNEL} -j MASQUERADE
        done


        ping ${SERVER_TUN_IP} -i 60 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo "local start."
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}


function  stop(){
    echo "Flushing iptables on server..."
    ssh -T root@${SERVER_SSH_IP} -p ${SERVER_SSH_PORT} "iptables -F"

    echo "Flushing iptables on localhost..."
    iptables -F

    echo "Killing ssh tunnel..."
    CLIENT_SSH_PID=`ps -ef | grep "ssh -NTCf -w ${CLIENT_TUNNEL#tun}:${SERVER_TUNNEL#tun}" | grep -v grep | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [ -n "${CLIENT_SSH_PID}" ]; then 
        kill -9 ${CLIENT_SSH_PID}
    fi
    if [ -n "`pidof ping`" ]; then 
        pidof ping | xargs kill -9 
    fi
}

function usage(){
    echo "usage:"
    echo "    $0 -start"
    echo "    $0 -stop"
    echo ""
    echo "for ssh:"
    echo "    nohup $0 -start > /dev/null 2>&1"
}

case $1 in
    "--start" | "-start")
        start
        ;;
    "--stop" | "-stop")
        stop
        ;;
    *)
        usage
        ;;
esac
```