# Forward VPN traffic to another server

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, forwarding, wireguard

I have 2 servers: 
**server A**: `Public IP --> 104.x.x.x`
**server B**: `Public IP --> 188.x.x.x`

**server A** has 2 VPN servers:
`Openvpn  --> tun0`
`Wireguard  --> wg0`

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 fe80::ae7d:f7ab:615b:a78a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 304 (304.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.9.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.9.0.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 22563  bytes 14268224 (14.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20017  bytes 15166196 (15.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 6 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want that if any clients connect to **openvpn** or **wireguard**, instead of connecting to internet from **server A**, use **server B** internet connction

`Clients (Openvpn or wireguard)` **-->** `Server A` **-->** `Server B` **-->** `Connect to internet`

**How can I make in possible? (using ssh or other way to forward traffic from server A to server B)**

Thank you,
**Best regards**

Comment: The usual way to forward traffic is through routing. Are **server A** and **server B** on a common private network?

Comment: You need to use policy based routing (so you can select a routing table based on something other then destination - usually a source IP, or a QoS mark which can be set based on interface using iptables).

Comment: Hello there,actually server A is in usa and Server B is in france and using public ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to establish a VPN link between server A and B, let's say server B will get `10.10.0.1` as address, server A `10.10.0.2` and the virtual interface on server A will be called `tun1`. You can use whichever technology you fill more comfortable.

Then, as remarked by **davidgo**, you need to use policy based routing on server A. In order to do so:

1. Add a new routing table to the file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

   ```
   200 vpn
   ```
2. Add a selection rule to use the routing table `vpn` for all traffic coming from the private network:

   ```
   ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/8 table vpn
   ```
3. Fill the routing table

   ```
   ip route add 10.8.0.0/16 dev tun0 src 10.8.0.1 table vpn
   ip route add 10.9.0.0/16 dev wg0 src 10.9.0.1 table vpn
   ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 dev tun1 src 10.10.0.2 table vpn
   ip route add default via 10.10.0.1 dev tun1 table vpn
   ```

Comment: you mean that I have to create tun1 interface with ip 10.10.0.1 on server A that connected to server B and then set Iptables rules  on server A?
Thank's

Comment: Yes, you must establish a VPN tunnel between server A and server B, e.g. OpenVPN you are already familiar with. The policy based routing table is for server A, while I assume server B will have a private IP `10.10.0.1`. You can obviously assign different IP's and have different virtual `tun*` interfaces.

Comment: I set `10.0.0.100` on interface **tun1** on server A and with `ssh -w`  command, create establish connection from server B to server A (server A private IP `10.0.0.200`)
but can't connect to internet
can you help me more please?

Comment: On server B you need a `SNAT/MASQUERADING` rule in the `nat` table of iptables (`iptables -t nat -nvL POSTROUTING` to list the rules). **ssh** is a bad choice as VPN tunnel since it uses TCP (all packets are sent in order, packets lost are resent, etc.). Start debugging by pinging server B's private address.

Comment: Actually I have to use ssh due some restriction
I can ping private ip from both servers
`10.0.0.100` from server B and `10.0.0.200` from server A

Comment: So you just need something like `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j MASQUERADE` on server B and you can test with `ping -I 10.0.0.100 8.8.8.8` on server A.

Comment: unfortunate I can't ping
If there is no problem, Can I have your email to send you full detail about servers and configuration?
Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: The question you asked solves half your problem (the policy base routing for clients). I don't use ssh tunnels, check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/782220/how-to-make-ssh-based-vpn) to set it up or ask a new question (linking this one) if it does not solve all your problems.